# Integrating $\int \sqrt{2me-mkr^2-\frac{1}{2}m br^4 - \frac{a^2}{r^2}} \,dr$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, substitution, hamilton-equations

I was trying to find Hamiltons principle function, $S$,  for the Hamiltonian:

$$ H = \frac{1}{2} m \left( P_{r}^2 + \frac{P_{\theta}^2}{r^2} \right) + \frac{1}{2}kr^2 + \frac{1}{4} b r^4$$

After considering the form $S = f(r, \theta) - Et = R(r) + \Theta(\theta) - Et$ and identifying the canonical momenta with the partial derivatives of $S$ I got to:

$$ \left(\frac{dR}{dr} \right)^2 r^2 + mkr^4 + \frac{1}{2}mbr^6 - 2mEr^2 = -\left(\frac{d \Theta}{d \theta} \right)^2 $$

Each side must be a constant, $-a^2$, and so:

$$ \frac{dR}{dr} =  \sqrt{2mE-mkr^2-\frac{1}{2}m br^4 - \frac{a^2}{r^2}} $$

which leads to:

> $$ R(r)=  \int \sqrt{2mE-mkr^2-\frac{1}{2}m br^4 - \frac{a^2}{r^2}} \,dr$$

I've tried to find a substitution of variables to make it simpler but to no luck. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide context and at least *try*$ to solve the integral so that it's visible. Otherwise your question will unfortunately get closed.

Comment: Hamiltons principle function, $S$,  is the replacement we find for the action, S, which is the integral of the Lagrangian over time. It depends on the coordinates $x^i$ and time $t$.

Comment: If it gives me the final result of this integral, then yes!

Comment: Does it give us any advantage over the one I wrote? Yes, ultimately I was looking for a closed form of my integral

Comment: The only advantage is as an arclength function because I see the square root around every thing. There is an ugly elliptic integral closed form of this which I cannot find out how to do. I deleted some previous comments to make room.

Comment: Sorry for the “lazy solution”, but here is the closed form solution: simply make [$$R(r)=\int\sqrt{Ar^4+Br^2+C+Dr^{-2}}\mathrm dr$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28A*r%5E4%2BB*r%5E2%2BC%2BD*r%5E-2%29) as your variables consequently above. There may not be anyone here willing to figure this out, so to be lazy and save some time, here is the long solution. 

_I can still post the other solution if you want. It is pretty interesting with the arc length integral_.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{2mE-mkr^2-\frac12mbr^4-\frac{a^2}{r^2}}\,dr=\frac1r\sqrt{2mEr^2-mkr^4-\frac12mbr^6-a^2}\,dr$$
Now with the substitution $u=r^2\Rightarrow dr=\frac{du}{2r}$ so:
$$\frac{1}{2u}\sqrt{2mEu-mku^2-\frac12mbu^3-a^2}du$$
so we have reduced the order of the polynomial inside the square root. However, integrals of this form do not have "nice" closed-form solutions and so you are probably going to end up with a special function/series to represent this